# Replace INDIRECT Array Output with Cell References

Tags: microsoft-excel

**Setup**

I have a mysterious formula that looks like this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT({"A1:D1";"F1:I1"}), 2019, INDIRECT({"A2:D2";"F2:I2"})))
```

[image: SUMIF with Array Indirect]

**Question**

I wish to replace the `INDIRECT()` functions with direct cell references. So I wish I could use a formula that looks like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF((A1:D1, F1:I1), 2019, (A2:D2, F2:I2)))
```

But this returns `#VALUE!`

Is there any way to make this work?

I have tried creating Named Ranges that hold the non-contiguous ranges. That does not help. Making it an array formula does not help either.

**Things I have looked at**

I stepped through the working formula with the Evaluate Formula tool, there is a step where the `INDIRECT()` functions evaluate to a `#VALUE!` error. But the formula still works.

[image: INDIRECTs evaluate to #VALUE! error]

So it's like there is something special about `INDIRECT()` which returns an array of the ranges that `SUMIF()` can accept, even though the intermediate steps evaluate to an error.

I have also used the `F9` tool in the formula editor to evaluate the formula piece by piece. Interestingly, if you follow the same steps as the Evaluate Formula too, the formula evaluates to an error.

I am highly curious to know more about what is going on when `INDIRECT()` is returning an array of ranges. So I would appreciate if anyone could shed light on that.

This SO question touches on this topic, but doesn't really explain it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124173/row-function-behaves-differently-inside-sum-and-sumproduct

Thanks!

Comment: Outside of doing 2 sumif: `=SUMIF(A1:D1, 2019, A2:D2)+SUMIF(F1:I1, 2019,  F2:I2)` Indirect is the only method to pass disjointed ranges to SUMIF.

Comment: Just saw that @ScottCraner answered 53 seconds before me—should I delete my response?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SuperUser.

I'm not quite sure how your sumproduct worked, but you can use these sumif formulas to achieve the same result.

```
=SUMIF(A1:D1, 2019, A2:D2)+SUMIF(F1:I1,2019,F2:I2)
```

Comment: No, leave it. mine was a comment.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I have a constraint that I can't re-write the formula. I have to replace the ``INDIRECT()`` calls with cell references. It seems like that's not going to be possible per @ScottCraner 's comment. 